# GraphQL (Prisma) Mutation data undefined

Tags: reactjs, graphql, prisma

I’m trying to do a mutation and I keep getting an error about data being null on the React side. However, if I try the same mutation in the GraphQL console it works. Also, I know the endpoint is working because I can Query data with no problem.

Everything

## Server code (resolver):

```
 async signup(parent, args, ctx, info) {
    // lowercase their email
    args.email = args.email.toLowerCase();
    // hash their password
    const password = await bcrypt.hash(args.password, 10);
    // create the user in the database
    const user = await ctx.db.mutation.createUser({
        data: { 
          ...args,
          password,
        }
      }, info);
    return user;
}
```

## Mutation (React Side)

```
mutation signupUser($email: String!, $password: String!, $name: String!) {
  signup(email: $email, password: $password, name: $name) {
    __typename
    id
    email
    password
    name
  }
}
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at Mutation._this.onMutationCompleted (react-apollo.esm.js:477)
    at react-apollo.esm.js:434
```

Also here is a snippet of my Mutation on the component

```
<Mutation
        mutation={signUpUserMutation}
        onCompleted={(user) => {
          handleClose();
        }}
        onError={(error) => {
          console.log(error)
          setOpen(true);
        }}
      >
        {signup => (
          <Form
            onSubmit={async (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
              await signup({
                variables: {
                  name: values.name,
                  email: values.email,
                  password: values.password,
                },
              });
              setSubmitting(false);
            }}
          >
            {({
              values, errors, handleChange, handleBlur, isSubmitting,
            }) => (
```

Comment: I figured it out. I think it was because I didn't have a WebSocket connection. Idk, either way, it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your schema

```
type User {
    id: Int
    name: String
    email: String
    password: String
}
type Response {
    status: Boolean
    message: String
    data: User
}
type Mutation {
    signUp(name: String!, email: String!, password: String!) : Response
}
```

On Mutation resolver signUp function

```
 async signUp(parent, args, { db }, info) {
    // lowercase their email
    args.email = args.email.toLowerCase();
    // hash their password
    const password = await bcrypt.hash(args.password, 10);
    // create the user in the database
    const data = { 
        ...args, 
        password,
    }
    const user = await db.mutation.createUser(data, info);
    return user;
 }
```

in database mutation createUser function you can access like that

```
const createUser = async ({ name, email, password }, info) => {
  try {
      // Code to save user information in database
    return { status: true,
             message: "User registration successful. You can login now.", 
             data: createdUser
    }
  } catch(e) {
    return { status: false, message: e.message, data: null }
  }
}
```

And your query

```
mutation signupUser($email: String!, $password: String!, $name: String!) {
  signup(email: $email, password: $password, name: $name) {
    status
    message
    data {
     id
     email
     password
     name
    }
  }
}
```